# Subset of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many subsets does the set containing a single element which is an empty set have? I know that an empty set is a subset of any set including itself but what would be the number of subsets in a set containing an empty set? Is it infinitely many or none?

Comment: *Any* set $A$ that contains exactly one element has two subsets: the empty set and $A$ itself. How the element 'looks like' (e.g. it is the empty set) is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{\varnothing\}$ has one element. So it has exactly *two* subsets. $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$.